# Is the following answer grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Here's the sentence: **"The most interesting trip had to be our year nine graduation trip".** It was an answer to the question **"What was the most interesting trip?"**

If it is correct, how can I prove that it is? If not, how can this sentence be corrected?

Comment: What do you think might be wrong with it?

Comment: Not sure, my english teacher said it was wrong but didn't really explain why.

Comment: Well, I can't find anything wrong with it. It reads perfectly fine to me. So either a) your teacher is wrong, or b) you haven't repeated everything word-for-word.

Comment: I have repeated everything word-for-word. My teacher is russian and believes that a student can't know better than her, so that's a problem. Still, I'll try to explain this to her. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, it is a grammatically correct answer that makes sense. The response is in line with the question. The question asks for a statement as to what the most interesting trip was; the answer states that 'it had to be our year nine graduation trip'.

It checks out fine